# Play Framework Html class and Form Rendering without Input

Tags: forms, templates, playframework

I have 2 questions. Version 2.4.x of the Play! Framework.

1. Whenever I render a layout using `layoutName.render(inputargs...);` it returns an "Html" object. I have not found a reference to this class in any of the docs. Where do I find this class? [This doesn't seem to yield anything.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/index.html) (Edit2: Found in play.twirl.api.Html)
2. I am rendering a search bar on every page which is created using an input form. The problem is that the main layout needs my model class for the form as an argument: `mainLayout.render("title", something_else, new Form<Search>());` Is there any way of writing it as `mainLayout.render("title", something_else);` whilst still retaining the form?

Edit3: Apparently the form is not needed at all; so long the name of the input is the same as the model's name any form will work:

    `@helper.form(action = routes.SearchPage.search()) {
    <input type="text" name="term">
    }`

 will work for a search term, but only as long as "term" is a public variable of the class in which we are going to store the post data.

Edit:
Currently using a method that inserts the empty form. The problem is that the Html class is not found. I have no idea where it is located.

```
public static Html renderMainLayout(String title, java.util.ArrayList<String> content) {
    play.data.Form<Search> userForm = play.data.Form.form(Search.class);
    return layout.render(title, content, userForm);
}
```

Comment: For **1**, the play templating engine has been factored out into twirl: https://github.com/playframework/twirl  I can't seem to find scaladocs for it, but you can still find it in Play 2.x docs (don't think very much has changed).

Comment: Can't seem to find the Html class in the 2.0.8 docs.

Comment: Hmm perhaps it won't show up in the javadocs as it was written in scala. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.Html

Comment: That's just it; the symbol is not found whenever I replace Html with play.api.templates.Html.

Comment: It's now `play.twirl.api.Html`

Comment: It works. How did you find it (so I can find it myself in the future)?

Comment: https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/e36a84922f933bb441b736560c7a6fb22f2b934a/api/src/main/scala/play/twirl/api/Formats.scala#L23-44